# Debugging child processes- GDB/DDD

Tags: debugging, gdb, child-process

My project is to implement a simple shell program with background processing by way of ending an arglist with &, as in most UNIX shells.  My problem is how to debug the shell in GDB when background processing requires child processes to be created.

My child processing code goes like

```
int id;
int child=-1;
int running=0;

if ((strcmp(args[0], "&")==0){

  if ((id==fork())==-1)
    perror("Couldn't start the background process");

  else if (id==0){  //start the child process
    running++;
    printf("Job %d started, PID: %d\n", running, getpid());
    signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);
    signal(SIGQUIT, SIG_DFL);
    execvp(args[0], args);
    perror("Can't execute command);
    exit(1);

  else {
    int jobNum= running-(running-1);

   if ( (waitpid(-1, &child, WNOHANG) == -1)
     perror("Child Wait");

   else 
     printf("[%d] exited with status %d\n", jobNum, child>>8);
}
```

When I try to run a command, like ps &, and set the breakpoint to the function parser, the command executes without hitting the breakpoint.  This is confusing and renders the debugger useless in this instance.  What can I do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want

```
set follow-fork-mode child
```

also note that the line

```
if ((id==fork())==-1)
```

is comparing an uninitialized value against the return value of fork().
I believe you wanted an assignment.

Comment: @jason the gdb command 'set follow-fork-mode' tells gdb what to do when it encounters a fork, which side of the fork it should continue debugging, the parent side, or the child side.